# Highstock / Highcharts dataGrouping points outside of viewport / canvas

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the `dataGrouping` setting in Highstock to group data by time.
It works fine if as long as I have multiple ticks on the x-axis (e.g. when using `day` as `unit`).
Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5bpj3dgu/

When I change the `unit` to `year`, I expect to have only one tick on the x-axis in the center. But instead, the only point is located to the left outside the viewport / canvas. The chart looks completely empty. Only when you hover, you get a tool tip that indicates the above behaviour.
Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5bpj3dgu/1/

Also, I noticed that I have to use `forced: true` in order to get Highcharts to do the `dataGrouping` at all which I do not understand.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`dataGrouping` is supported in Highstock, so when using `StockChart` constructor the chart is working. It is possible to disable not needed features though options.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36o50rp4/

`dataGrouping` has an option [`smoothed`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.smoothed) that will allow you placing a point in the middle of a grouped range.

Compare 2 series with different `smoothed` option: https://jsfiddle.net/36o50rp4/1/

However, if there is no reason for Highstock to start xAxis from an empty space, then it won't, so two series with `smoothed` set to false will create a chart with points on left edge of the chart. This can be solved by setting `min` for xAxis or `minPadding`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36o50rp4/2/

Comment: Using `smoothed: true` fixes the problem described by the OP for me. @kacper-madej Thanks for this but can I ask: do you know why this option isn't true by default?

Comment: @OliverLloyd It seems that this might be so, because `smoothed: false` is more commonly used option - a group is indexed by the start of that group.